# Cells in tissues

Tags: anatomy

**Tissue (biology):** In biology, tissue is a cellular organizational level intermediate between cells and a complete organ. A tissue is an ensemble of similar cells from the same origin that together carry out a specific function.(Wikipedia)
Are all the cells of a tissue of a kind?

In the definition Tissue  what is from the same origin?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please read the instructions on constructing good questions. A title should be a one line phrase indicating what the question is about, not an extract from WIkipedia. Also, you are expected to write in standard English and a single question mark after a question is sufficient. I have corrected your question. Please try to do better next time.

Answer (score 4):

What you say is true that **most of the cells in a tissue are of the same kind.** However, as with most rules in biology, there is almost always an exception to these rules. There are only four types of tissues (can be split up into further subdivisions): muscle, epithelial, connective and nervous. Also, a **muscle tissue** is made up of an ensemble of myocytes (**muscle cells**). Therefore, the answer to your question would be yes, the cells in a tissue are (if not all, then) almost all of the same kind.

Answer (score 0):

Many different types/kinds of cells comprise a single tissue.  For instance, the epithelial tissue of mammalian skin can contain cells that produce hair, excrete sweat, or do neither of these things but simply serve as a barrier.  These cells are all epithelial tissue.   Here is another example of the diversity of cell types in a single tissue: the cells of the brain are part of 'nervous tissue', but there are thousands of different kinds of neuronal cells (the precise number is growing actually; see [this website](http://neuromorpho.org), where this image was grabbed).

[image]

Blood is technically a tissue, and yet there are many, many different kinds of blood cells.

[image: Basic types of blood cells]

In reference to your second question, the cells share a common origin in a tissue because they come from a small number of precursor cells, like the depiction in the image above for blood cells.